# MySQL Workbench SQL Scripts Editor Panel

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Im working on an EER Model in MySQL Workbench 6.2 Now when I forward engineer to get a script i want some custom SQL Script to be added to it. I saw that its possible by adding a SQL Script in the **SQL Scripts Panel** though when i tried to add a file to it and write some code into it i cannot save the file to the EER

[image: Image to see what i'm having]

Comment: This works for me. I applied changes to both new scripts (created from within Workbench) and added scripts (added already existing scripts). However, I used 6.3.5 while you state you use an old 6.2 version.

Comment: I tried it again yesterday and for some reason it worked on my work computer its using the same version on the laptop im using. Though the day i posted this it didnt work on the workcomputer either.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an SQL file to the model is indirectly possible, by creating a new SQL script and loading your file into that.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate on that cause to what i see on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-views-overview-scripts.html its possible

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Read my updated answer.